# Resharper 5 XML comment format

Tags: resharper

When using Resharper XML comment formatting it ends up formatting like this example (note the indentation):

```
/// <summary>
///     Gets the extension's type
/// </summary>
```

I would like it to do this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the extension's type </summary>
```

Is there any way to configure this?

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 3):

As of July 4th 2011, there is no option to format XML comments in ReSharper.

Source - http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/305502;jsessionid=CD1ACAF582C865B28312F2A03B0E69C0?tstart=0

There is a feature request logged here - http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-44782?projectKey=RSRP&query=xml+comment

Comment: If you're on v6.1 or higher, you can disable XML comments reformatting: ReSharper > Options > Code Editing > Code Cleanup > (Select profile) > C# > Disable Reformat embedded XML doc comments.

Answer (score 2):

ReSharper 7.1 EAP allows you to configure XML doc comment formatting. Go to Code Editing | XML Doc Comments | Formatting style and turn off "Indent text inside tag" and "Line breaks after header and before footer...".